# Fireworks Ethernet Firing System

Tags: circuit-design

It's been awhile that i've been down the EE path, and since it will be firework season soon, I wanted to try my hands at a very basic firing system without using any resistors or diodes. The e-matches at the end of the system need a good 1000mah, so i'm planning to use 24AWG UTP 8Wire Cat6 under 300ft with a 24V/3000mA battery.

Using the eight wires, I would make one a ground and run that to a selector to make one out of the four rails active at a time. Each of the seven push buttons would then be wired to one of the same color across all four rails. So button one would be all purple, and when pressing it, it would simply try to throw current down all four rails on the purple wire, but with the selector only on rail one, only channel one on rail one would fire as that is a complete circuit.

Make sense? It's a bit of a mess, but hopefully it came out sort of clear. I'm pretty sure I can get away with this without any sort of resistors or diodes, so this is super simple. My one concern is that can anyone see a chance of a missfire with this? With a common ground there shouldnt be any stray current going anywhere else, but idk.

[image]

Comment: do you know why you have to turn off transmitters when you enter a blasting zone at a road construction?

Comment: 1) Your schematic is completely incomprehensible -- I really can't tell what you're trying to convey with all the crisscrossing colored lines. Please redraw it. 2) What type of igniters are you using on your fireworks? Details matter.

Comment: What does ethernet have to do with this...?

Comment: I think the schematic is comprehensible, personally. Sure it's unconventional but it's not that crazy.

Comment: What I want to know is how the one pentapod at the top defeated the four at the bottom? Is it because he has the multi-colour death-ray?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your schematic is far from clear. Is this what you are trying to make?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2faYc24.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. The basic layout of what you are proposing. One detonator box shown.*

> when pressing it, it would simply try to throw current down all four rails on the purple wire,

Throwing current is not a term we use. We switch voltage to the line and if there is a load connected to the line then current will flow or "be drawn".

---

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fMSrY1.png)</sup>

*Figure 2. The problem with this arrangement is that there are alternate current paths. If SW3 is pressed while SW8 is closed full voltage will be applied to R3 (current path indicated in red). Meanwhile alternate current paths are provided as shown in blue and these will exist for the other detonator boxes too. This current might be high enough to detonate other channels too.*

To avoid the current sneak paths you would need to add a diode in series with each detonator.

Comment: I appreciate the redraw, I find that a bit hard to follow honestly, but I believe that is what I was trying to convey. My concern is if that circuit continued to the right more, and detonator box 2 was shown connected to SW1-7 as detonator 1 is, the sole thing keeping SW1 from firing both detonator 1 and 2 at the same time, is SW8 is selected, and not SW9. SW1/SW8 would be the only closed circuit at that instant so I would like to believe it would be the only one to fire. Just not sure if I'm over looking something. Thank you. I'm going to have to try that site out.

Comment: You will need the diodes there are sneak paths through the other boxes. Follow the path SW3 R10 back through R8-9 and R11-14 then through R1-R2 and R4-R7 to ground.

Comment: That's what I said, isn't it? Did I miss something?

Comment: They are not detonators (The flame front is subsonic, they are electric matches or igniters) and I would be careful here as IME the required ignition current varies widely from one sample to the next, it is entirely possible for the sneak circuit current to fire the wrong one. Incidentally a nice to have is a led and series resistance in series with the battery (Bypassed by a switch) so that you can put the thing in 'test' mode and confirm circuit continuity after wiring everything up and clearing the range. A keyswitch is a good addition so you can safe the thing when out wiring up.

Comment: I do plan to put a safety switch, and would eventually put in a test circuit after I got the base of it in.

Comment: That was my concern with the sneak current. Is there a way to calculate what kind of diode that is needed when the ematch requires anywhere from 500mah to 1500mah, and the length from the switch box to detonator will be anywhere from a few feet to 300+?

Comment: I would assume a diode in forward direction on the positive side of the "R"s, would prevent the circuit going back up through the others?

Comment: @Transistor Absolutely, you did not miss anything I think the OP did.

Comment: @SephYuyX: Your question assumes that everyone knows what an e-match is and has no link to a datasheet for the type you are using.

Comment: True, yes I did, but theres not much more detail to them outside of needing a trigger amperage of between 500mah and 1500mah, so anything below that would be safe. It's just two wires with either a chemical or electronic+chemical reaction when the appropriate amperage triggers it. My concern would be trying to figure out a diode that would work both in a short run of wire vs a very long run of wire. The idea would be to hot swap cable lengths with the different "detonator" units, but it would almost need to have the diodes spliced inline with the wire instead of the unit.

Comment: The current is measured in mA. mAh (not mah) is a measure of battery capacity.

Comment: @Transistor Someone suggested just using an 8P4T rotary switch instead. Seems like that should fix any sort of current sneak I'd think since that isolates it only to one detonator at a time, and it shouldn't be possible for one R activation to go to the others.

Comment: Draw the schematic and look for sneak paths as shown in my Figure 2.

Comment: @Transistor Hopefully I did a better job with this schematic.. https://i.imgur.com/tr8SohP.png Try my best I dont think I can find any viable sneak path. My understanding of these multi-pole switches is that each pole is completely segregated from the others in the same throw, and obviously the other throws are segregated from each other too. I think in this set up it would be the most straight forward without any need for diodes, and mitigate any sneak path issues. Do you see anything that would be of concern? Thanks again for your help.

Comment: Pressing B1, while the Negative SPST switch is closed, and Rail1 is selected, it should only be firing SQ1.

Comment: That should work.